# Is there a sourcecode management system (svn, git, etc.) webclient that can commit?

Tags: svn, git, webclient, version-control

Is there a sourcecode management system (svn, git, etc.) webclient which you can use to change the code (that can commit and push)?
I am hosting my repository at sourceforge.

Comment: in what way could changing code ruin the system?

Comment: It's been a while since I posted this question but I believe I meant that it should be a proper commit + push and not just a code edit.

Comment: I made that part more clear in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polarion web client for SVN seems to be able to it.

http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_webclient.php

I didn't test it, though.